# Which is language is best for MCU to PC Communication applications?

Tags: programming-languages, tcp, microcontroller

I am looking forward to learn a language mainly for my electronic projects. My projects may include PC to MCU communications, TCP/IP (like catching new facebook comments and sending it to MCU) etc. I have seen a lot of similar projects using python and perl. So which one will be better and easier to learn as well as to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of suggesting something "weird" -- you might want to take a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/) and its microcontroller counterpart [Wiring](http://wiring.org.co/).  They are designed for exactly this sort of use case.

Comment: I didn't understand your reply. Maybe you have misunderstood my question.